# Do Nexus 5, Nexus7 and Nexus10 device on the market directly support RenderScript GPU compute?

Tags: android, gpgpu, gpu, renderscript

Running renderscript code on GPU seems to require some "extra" effort than writing high renderscript quality code.

Though People from Google demonstrated that Nexus 7 could do GPU compute by renderscript (at 25:50 in the video https://www.uplinq.com/schedule/renderscript-and-opengl-es-30-new-technologies-adreno-gpu), and PowerVR said its GPU would support Renderscript GPU compute (http://withimagination.imgtec.com/index.php/powervr/running-renderscript-efficiently-with-powervr-gpus-on-android). But seems to enable renderscript GPU compute, new GPU driver is always required. Or else only CPU will be used.

Since I don't have budget to buy Nexus5, 7, 10 and try them out, I'd like to ask if those devices on the market directly support renderscript GPU compute.

Other than Nexus, is there any other device on the market directly supports this? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nexus 4, 5, 7 (2013 model only, not the original one), and 10 all support GPU compute for RenderScript. At the current point in time, every Nexus device sold in the Play Store has GPU-accelerated RenderScript. Nexus is the fastest and easiest way to get the latest features of Android, but other Qualcomm Adreno devices and Samsung Exynos5-based devices will also be able to use these GPU compute drivers for RS. Already today, the Galaxy S4 (Exynos-5 based version) has a native RS GPU driver, although the non-Exynos version does not.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer. When using Nexus, do I have to use filterscript, like what the powervr link in the question text indicated. Or I can just use renderscript probably with relax precision? And do I have to use script group?

Comment: You do not need to use FilterScript. I do suggest that you use "__attribute ((kernel))" instead of the old pointer-based variants. Relaxed precision will also make things run faster (assuming your algorithms can tolerate the reduced precision requirements). ScriptGroup is just a helper API. You can also execute your kernels as standalone units and create DAGs/pipelines without it. We just provide it as a way to do cross-kernel optimizations.

Comment: Since Nexus 5 was recently released, is there a 2012 model? Is there any chance to get any Nexus 5 or Nexus 10 that doesn't direct support Renderscript GPU compute on the market(just want to be really sure)? Thanks a lot!

Comment: I got Nexus5, it supports gpu compute.